# How do I change the content of my listview when an item in my spinner is selected?

Tags: android, json, listview, android-fragments, spinner

In my android app, I have a spinner and a listview. The spinner and listview data are populated by json. They are inside a fragment. My question is how do i change the content in my listview without changing the entire screen when an item in the spinner is selected? Thanks

Here is my spinner code

```
 try
        {
            URL url = new URL (Config.URL_SPIN);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try
        {
            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json;


            e_name = new String[JA.length()];
            e_gender = new String[JA.length()];

            for(int i = 0; i<JA.length(); i++)
            {
                json        =  JA.getJSONObject(i);
                e_gender[i] =  json.getString("e_gender");
                e_name[i]   =  json.getString("e_name");
            }
            list1.add("All");
            list1.add("NonSports");
            for(int i = 0; i<e_name.length; i++)
            {
                list1.add(e_name[i] + " "+e_gender[i]);
            }



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        spinner_fn();



        return rootView;


    }


private void spinner_fn() {
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list1);
        spinner1.setAdapter(spinner);
        spinner1.setSelection(0);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {




        }
```

Here is my JSON code for the spinner

```
lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        spinner1 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sp1);
        getJSON();
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL (Config.URL_SPIN);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {
        JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject json;


        e_name = new String[JA.length()];
        e_gender = new String[JA.length()];

        for(int i = 0; i<JA.length(); i++)
        {
            json        =  JA.getJSONObject(i);
            e_gender[i] =  json.getString("e_gender");
            e_name[i]   =  json.getString("e_name");
        }
        list1.add("All");
        list1.add("NonSports");
        for(int i = 0; i<e_name.length; i++)
        {
            list1.add(e_name[i] + " "+e_gender[i]);
        }



    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    spinner_fn();



    return rootView;


}
```

And here is for the ListView

```
private void showResult() {
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY2);

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
            String teamone = jo.getString(Config.TAG_teamone);
            String teamonepts = jo.getString(Config.TAG_teamonepts);
            String teamtwo = jo.getString(Config.TAG_teamtwo);
            String teamtwopts = jo.getString(Config.TAG_teamtwopts);
            String e_name = jo.getString(Config.TAG_e_name);
            String e_gender = jo.getString(Config.TAG_e_gender);
            String m_no = jo.getString(Config.TAG_m_no);
            HashMap<String, String> match = new HashMap<>();
            match.put(Config.TAG_teamone, teamone);
            match.put(Config.TAG_teamonepts, teamonepts);
            match.put(Config.TAG_teamtwo, teamtwo);
            match.put(Config.TAG_teamtwopts, teamtwopts);
            match.put(Config.TAG_e_name, e_name);
            match.put(Config.TAG_e_gender, e_gender);
            match.put(Config.TAG_m_no, m_no);
            list.add(match);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            getActivity(), list, R.layout.gamesadapterlayout,
            new String[]{Config.TAG_teamone, Config.TAG_teamonepts, Config.TAG_teamtwo, Config.TAG_teamtwopts, Config.TAG_e_name, Config.TAG_e_gender, Config.TAG_m_no},
            new int[]{R.id.team1, R.id.score1, R.id.team2, R.id.score2, R.id.Type, R.id.s_gender});
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void getJSON() {
    class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            JSON_STRING = s;
            showResult();
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            s = rh.sendGetRequest(Config.URL_GAMES);
            return s;
        }
    }
    GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
    gj.execute();
}
```

Comment: Do you need to call another Json request when you select an item in the spinner?

Comment: simply create a new object for your list view whenever some value is set in the spinner and the set the adapter `adapter = new SimpleAdapter(whatever,new,values,you,need,to,pass);` then set the adapter `lv.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: @SakuraFukuyoshi yes I am trying to call another json request whenever the user selects a value from the spinner

Comment: So how will you know what json request will you call when an item has been selected? Is it also in an ArrayList?

list1 array is for the items that will be displayed in the spinner right?

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not clear that do you need to call API every time user selects item from your spinner? In this case there would be 2 possibilities.

**FIRST**

Get all the data from your server in one request only that is data for your spinner and data for each value of your spinner item to show in ListView. And arrange this data into HashMap structure. Something like this:

```
HashMap<String,Object> allData = new HashMap<>();
```

In HashMap your keys will be Spinner item and value will be listview data corresponding to that spinner item. Now whenever user select any item from your spinner get values according to that selected item and populate your listview with that data that is you need to set adapter again in your listview with new dataset.

**SECOND**

Fetch all data to display in spinner. Now, whenever user selects any item fetch data according to that selected item from your server and parse response and again set adapter for your listview with new dataset.

Hope this helps you.